# A Bachet equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

How to prove the Bachet equation

$y^2=x^3+45$

has no solution in $\mathbb{Z}$?

This is an exercise in *Elementary Number Theory and Its Application*, section 13.2.